# $C^l$ diffeomorphism between a smooth manifold and a $C^k$ manifold

Tags: functions, manifolds

Let $M$ and $N$ be two Riemannian manifolds. $M$ is smooth while $N$ is $C^k$ manifold.

Suppose there is a $C^l$ diffeomorphism between the two manifolds for $l \leq k$.

Is it true that $N$ is also a smooth manifold?

I am thinking of $M$ and $N$ being hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example, like those in these papers: 
http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0622v4.pdf

http://www.igpm.rwth-aachen.de/Download/reports/reusken/ARpaper51.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. A $C^\infty$-atlas is contained in a $C^k$-atlas, since all $C^\infty$-charts are $C^k$. So, in a sense, the answer is no.

On the other hand, if $N$ is $C^0$, $M$ is $C^\infty$, and $N$ is homeomorphic to $M$, then $N$ admits a smooth structure (Can you see it?) as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply. For the second sentence, I guess by smooth structure you mean the chart maps. 

Are you not assuming the homeomorphism to be smooth too for $N$ to admit a smooth structure??

Comment: What else would I mean by smooth structure? And yes, the homeomorphism needn't be smooth.

Comment: Then how would $N$ admit a smooth structure if the homeomorphism is not smooth?

Comment: Forgive me - I misspoke. We need only assume that the map is a homeomorphism. The induced structure is defined to make it smooth. Namely, the charts will be of the form $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$, where $\phi$ is a chart on $M$ and $\psi$ is the homeomorphism.

Comment: Yes but $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$ won't be smooth unless $\psi^{-1}$ is, right?

Comment: Look at the definition of smooth maps.